# Conveying "brother and sister + noun"

Tags: traduction, anglais

> [German and English are brother and sister languages.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Everything_German_Phrase_Book/5bfrDQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=German%20and%20English%20are%20brother%20and%20sister%20languages&pg=PT14&printsec=frontcover) (The Everything German Phrase Book
> A Quick Refresher for Any Situation. Edward Swick · 2008.)

Does

> L'allemand et l'anglais sont des langues frères et sœurs.

sound natural (in contexts like this)?

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't sound like English.

Comment: Ha, I wonder which language that book considers the brother and which the sister :) I've only ever heard of "sister languages" for this relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Frères et sœurs* or *frère et sœur* wouldn't work in French. We'd rather say ***[des langues sœurs](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/langue_s%C5%93ur#fr)***, e.g.:

> *Le français, l’italien et l’espagnol sont des langues sœurs.*

Comment: Merci ! Peut-on aussi dire, p.ex. >Matlab et Octave sont des logiciels/langages (de programmations) soeurs ?

Comment: Non, le genre ne colle pas (**une** langue mais **un** langage/ **un** logiciel). On pourrait éventuellement dire *des langages frères* mais probablement plutôt *langages apparentés* ou *langages similaires*.